# How to display JSON data in Xamarin.forms list view?

Tags: json, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to `xamarin.forms`, and i want to build an cross platform app that will display JSON data in the list view. This is my JSON data.

```
{
  "fish_product": [
    {
      "fish_id": "1",
      "fish_img": "",
      "fish_name": "Indian Mackerel",
      "fish_category": "Marine Fish",
      "size": "Medium",
      "price": "100"
    },
    {
      "fish_id": "2",
      "fish_img": "",
      "fish_name": "Manthal Repti",
      "fish_category": "Marine Fish",
      "size": "Small",
      "price": "200"
    },
    {
      "fish_id": "4",
      "fish_img": "",
      "fish_name": "Baby Sole Fish",
      "fish_category": "Marine Fish",
      "size": "Small",
      "price": "600"
    }
 ]
}
```

I want to display "fish_name" in list view. please suggest any solution or any article or tutorial for this. thank you in advance.

Comment: Successfully got the response from your API?

Comment: No sir.Actually this type of json Data we have to show.Can suggest some code?@Alex Chengalan

Comment: Try out this : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/rest/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to deserialize this JSON to an object like

```
public class FishProduct
{
    public string fish_id { get; set; }
    public string fish_img { get; set; }
    public string fish_name { get; set; }
    public string fish_category { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<FishProduct> fish_product { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have to use a ListView where you set your `listview.ItemsSource = myList.fish_product`

Then you have to create a DataTemplate using `ViewCell`

In this ViewCell you can have a Label when you SetBinding the fish_name field. In code something like

```
Label label = new Label();
label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "fish_name");
```

I think you can take a look to [ListView Documents](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/)

Comment: Sir Can you suggest Async Call Example Please?@Alessandro Caliaro

Comment: async call for what? your question is "how to display..." you don't need async. You need bindings

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you

Your MODEL

```
public class FishProduct
{
    public string fish_id { get; set; }
    public string fish_img { get; set; }
    public string fish_name { get; set; }
    public string fish_category { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<FishProduct> fish_product { get; set; }
}
```

Webservice call and JSON Deserialisation

```
public async Task GetData()
{
 try
  {
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  var result = await client.GetAsync("http://yourJSON_Url");
  result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  string json = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  List<FishProduct>  res= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FishProduct>>(json);

  }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
   throw;
  }
}
```